# Get valid stripe subscription for the authenticated user on laravel-spark

Tags: php, laravel-5, strip, laravel-spark, laravel-cashier

I'm new to laravel-spark I need to get the current valid subscriptions for the authenticated user using stripe api's because my subscriptions table is not uptodate, so I can't use it for this purpose.

```
//this way I will get the subscriptions from subscriptions table 
//but this table is not uptodate 
$user = Auth::user();
$user->subscriptions
//so I need to update this table and get valid records from stipe api's
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think the problem might be that Auth::user() is returning a new instance of a user, therefore, it doesn't have any context to stripe or subscriptions

Comment: Should I use plain php package to accomplish this ?

Comment: Can you try 

`if (Auth::check())
{
    // Check if the user is logged in...
}`